# Backbone.js breaking the each loop while switching view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a singleton backbone view :

```
 TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
           initialize : function(){
            _.each(array,function(arrayElement){
               //-do something     
          });
       };

})
return TestView()
```

The problem is that i want to reuse this view but sometimes the array on which the 'each' loop is iterating is very large so when i switch views and re-enter (reuse) this view, the previous each loop is still running. Is there a way by which i can stop an already executing each loop while switching views?

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit more? Like "Why it is singleton" and what is an `array`, etc.

Comment: I see some red flags in your design.  Perhaps you're retrieving too much data? Perhaps you should not reuse the view?  In any case, if you must ask this question you should first review your design.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because `_.each` is synchronous operation and you do not have control over it via any flags or whatsoever.. I would suggest you to use recursive `setTimeout` (just to make it asynchronous and non blocking) with an offset of few milliseconds and maybe you will be able to interrupt the execution..

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

function asyncEach(elementsArray) {
  var element;

  if (globalFlag) {
    element = elementsArray.shift();

    // do something with element

    setTimeout(function () {
      asyncEach(elementsArray);
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.every()` instead of `_.each()`. Just be sure to return `true` or `false` to indicate whether to continue looping or not.

```
      initialize : function(){
        _.every(array,function(arrayElement){
           //-do something

           if (shouldIContinue) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
        });
```

Comment: i was hoping backbone provides something by which i can stop all function calls and loops when switching a view (in the meanwhile not destroying it)?